# How to round decimal numbers in Android

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double value to round up in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796746/double-value-to-round-up-in-java)

I am getting float number as input and I want it to round to 2 digits after decimal point.
i.e. for example if I get 18.965518 as input, I want it to be 18.97. How to do it?

Comment: wouldn't you want it to be 18.97?

Comment: @ Kaiser : you are right

Comment: @ userSeven7s: i was trying for solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the [`DecimalFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)object, similar to regular Java.

Try

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d)
{
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
}
```

(code example lifted from http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/4130-rounding-double-two-decimal-places.html)

Answer (score 45):

DecimalFormat uses String (thus allocates additional memory), a big overhead compared to

```
(float)Math.round(value * 100) / 100
```