# how to round 0.055 value to 0.06 in java. I have tried DecimalFormat but it returns 0.05

Tags: java, rounding

how to round 0.055 value to 0.06 in java. I have tried DecimalFormat but it returns 0.05

Comment: have you tried to use BigDecimal#setScale?

Comment: What is the variable type before rounding (String, double, BigDecimal etc.), is the type after rounding the same?

Comment: I have float values before rounding but I tried with BigDecimal and DecimalFormat. It din't work

Comment: All the solutions here works fine when the values are of double type but not when the values are of float type.

Comment: So use BigDecimal.ROUND_UP instead of BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP

Answer (score 2):

A kind of trivial way

```
double d = 0.055;       
d= Math.round(d* 100);
d= d/100;
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Nice approach! +1 for mathematical solution!

Comment: This will be fail; (double)Math.round(1.005 * 100) / 100

Comment: You may read  this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/why, actually it was a bug http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6430675 which already fixed on java 7

Answer (score 1):

This is good for you ;

```
new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(0.055)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.00");
String formate = df.format(0.055);
double finalValue = (Double)df.parse(formate) ;
System.out.println(finalValue);
```

Output:

```
0.06
```

Reference Link : [Double value to round up in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796746/double-value-to-round-up-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     double d = 0.055;
     DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
     System.out.println(f.format(d));
}
```

Output:

```
.06
```

Answer (score 0):

```
round(0.055, 2); // returns 0.06

public static double round(double value, int places) {
  if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

  BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
  bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  return bd.doubleValue();
}
```