# Android calculator number rounding

Tags: java, android

So my calculator gives me answer like *30.122345353* or something like that.

**Question**
How can i round it to *30.122* ?
Here is part of my code. I need it to round the answer what comes from (ans + "")

This is my code

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = 2 * num1;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");
```

Answer (score 2):

easy way for rounding double to int:

```
int result = ((int)(yourDouble+0.5));
```

or:

```
public Double roundMyValue(String value){
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.000");
return (Double)df.parse(df.format(value)) ;
}
```

or something easy:

```
public Double roundMyValue(String value){
double current=Double.parseDouble(value);
int temp = current*1000;
return (Double)temp/1000;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Sten is looking for rounding to 3 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DecimalFormat` like this -

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.###");
decimalFormat.format(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DecimalFormater :)

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.000");
String formate = df.format(ans); 
double finalValue = (Double)df.parse(formate) ;
```

That should solve your problem. But if you want additional help, this question was already answered in a different post on StackOverflow: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796746/double-value-to-round-up-in-java)

All the best :)

Please let me know of the outcome.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, but exactly where should i enter that code ?

Comment: Hi there, there are 2 ways to do it. You can either create a function to format any number by 3 decimal places, or you can place the code that I have shown you just above your "tv2.setText" statement. Good luck :) Let me know if theres anything else you require

Comment: If i just copy your code and do nothing else, then it doesnt round anything.

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/3981976) provides a way to round numbers to a certain number of decimal places

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can beside the other Answers also round the number by multiplying the result times 10^n where n stands for the last significant decimalpoint you wanna achieve then round this(adding 0.5 for proper rounding like mathematicians do)by casting to an int and then divide it by 10^3 back again

maybe a method like this would do the trick:

Java:

```
public double rndMyNmb(double number,int decimalPoint);
{
    number*=Math.pow(10,decimalPoint);
    number=(int)(number+0.5);
    return number/Math.pow(10,decimalPoint);
}
```

ofc you could write everything inside the method as one-liner:

```
return (double)((int)(number*Math.pow(10,decimalPoint)+0.5)/Math.pow(10,decimalPoint));
```

Comment: Thank you, but i really dont understand where i have to write that code :/ im new at this

Comment: lets say the value where your number is stored is called : myNumber

Comment: then you can round this number like this with the method i provided you:      `myNumber=rndMyNmb(myNumber,n); ` //for n just writze the number of decimals you want to get back....thats all the magic then :)